# Neo4j 2.0 and Java compatibility

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using `neo4j 2.0`.
echo $JAVA_Home shows me : /`usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre`
`java -version` shows me : `java version "1.7.0_25"`

But When I starting my server then it shows me warning
`WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7`.

What else does Neo4j want ??

Any help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME is not set to point to the a Java7 JRE.

On OSX, where I first noticed this problem, my JAVA_HOME is set in ~/.bash as

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

Comment: Hello Mike, but for me JAVA_HOME was set to jre .. actually there was some problem with utils file of neo4j..